# Return authtoken in response when user is created with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building an API using django-rest-framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org).

I am using the built in authtoken for user authentication.

Here is my issue: While I know that I can obtain a token.key by sending a POST containing valid username/password credentials to the method token_views.obtain_auth_token, I would like to return a valid token key to the client after registration.

My current solution is not secure and not at all desirable. Here is the code:
Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('email', 'password', 'id', 'token') #by having the token as a 
    #field, a get request returns a list of everyone AND their tokens!!!! no-bueno!

        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'date_joined')

    def get_token(self, validated_data):
        #where we populate the 'token' field above
        user = User.objects.filter(email=validated_data.email)
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        return token.key

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new User instance, given the validated data.
        """
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        email = validated_data.pop('email', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        if email is not None:
            instance.username = email.lower()
            instance.email = email.lower()
        instance.save()
        # Retrieves token associated with user (works)
        token = Token.objects.get(user=instance)
        # would like to send token back to client in json response

        return instance
```

So long story short, I only want to return a token value in the response after a user object has been successfully created. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just in case anyone else encounters a similar issue, my solution for this problem was simply to require authentication permissions for GET requests.

Comment: Code:


`class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
 """
 This class lists all existing users, and creates new users.
 """
 authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
 permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
 serializer_class = UserSerializer

 def get_queryset(self):

  queryset = User.objects.all()
  return queryset`

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting